# podspec ERROR: iOS file patterns: The `vendored_frameworks` pattern did not match any file

Tags: ios, cocoapods, carthage

I am using Carthage on my private pod. I added

```
s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'Carthage/Build/iOS/OAuthSwift.framework'
```

To my `SDK.podespec` file. I also tried:

```
s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'Carthage/Build/iOS/*.framework'
```

Found that `s.requires_arc = true` might be missing, but still getting the same error.

When I run the Example project everything works fine, as well as `pod lib lint` validation passes. When I try to push to the master repo, I am getting the following error:

> ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The `vendored_frameworks` pattern did not match any file.

Comment: I think you [have asked this question bevore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41012930/lib-lint-podspec-validation-passes-but-fails-when-pushing-to-master-repo-ven)

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the old one ;). Do you know the answer? Thanks

Comment: I do not see a reason why you would mix up Carthage and cocoaPods. Looks messy to me.

Comment: Spot on, I totally agree. Unfortunately I am forced as one of the pods on another project, uses a custom fork, which I also need to fork in order to get this private pod to work properly, otherwise I am getting conflicts of two different versions. Anyway, this is something I must do.